# OpenCL - Array values being overwritten

Tags: c, arrays, opencl

I've encountered a problem where my previous array elements get overwritten with the new values.

**What the code is attempting to do**

I originally had an array with 100 elements (all from a sine function, this was my input). It is essentially to act as a FIFO buffer and computer the average of the array as new inputs is pushed into the FIFO. The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to implement a moving average filter.

However, what happens is the output tends to overwrite the previous values.
For example, if the first element of the FIFO buffer was 1 (that would currently mean that the rest of the buffer has 0 in it), the output array at position 0 would have 0.01 as the value. The next time around, if the next input value was 0.9, the output value at index 1 would have (0.01+0.009). BUT this is where the value of index 0 also gets overwritten to the same value as index 1.

I decided to write the same code in java and it works perfectly fine. If anyone can figure out the issue I would really appreciate it.

```
kernel void lowpass(__global float *Array, __global float *Output) { 
    float fifo[100]; 
    int queueIn; 
    float tempVal; 
    queueIn = 0; 
    int idx = get_global_id(0); 
    Output[idx] = 0; 
    fifo[idx] = 0; 

    for(int i = queueIn; i < 3; i++){ 
        fifo[i] = Array[i]; 
        tempVal = (float)0; 
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ 
             tempVal = (float) (fifo[j]*(.01) + tempVal);
        } 
        Output[queueIn] = tempVal; 
        queueIn = queueIn + 1; 
    }
}
```

Note I have the for loops set to 3 for debugging purposes. From tracing the code, it should not be doing this. But then again, I could be missing something small.

**ALSO i have removed alot of the variables such as queueIn for debugging reasons, I just need to make the array not overwrite previous values.

Example output from cmd

[image]

Java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Input,output and fifo arrays
    float [] fifo = new float[100];
    float [] input = new float[100];
    float [] output = new float[100];

    //temporary value to hold computed result
    float temp = 0;

    //initialize array values to 0
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        fifo[i] = 0;
        input[i] = 0;
        output[i] = 0;
    }

    //I know this produces a constant result, but its just 
    //proof of concept. this array will have values of .707 throughout it
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        temp = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(45));
        input[i] = temp;
    }   

    int queueIn; 
    float tempVal; 
    tempVal=0; 
    queueIn = 0; 
    //Insert one value at a time into the fifo buffer (first for loop)
    for(int i = queueIn; i < 100; i++){ 
        fifo[i] = input[i]; 

        //reset to 0 so it can reaccumilate
        tempVal = 0;

        //accumilate the values in the array multiplied by a coefficient one value in 
        //the array changes every time the first for loop executes.
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){ 
            tempVal = (float) (fifo[j]*(0.01) + tempVal);

        } 
        //store the value in the current index of the output array. 
        output[queueIn] = tempVal; 
        queueIn = queueIn + 1;
    }

    //verify results
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        System.out.println(output[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You say it works in java. Can you post the java code? Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just posted the code. The main part is this, I have two for loops. The first for loop inserts one element at a time into the FIFO circular buffer. The next for loop kicks in after the element has been added and it recomputes the average of the whole array multiplied by a coefficient. End goal is to implement a moving average filter for a signal.

Comment: Rather than `0.01`, I'd expect `1.0/4` in `(fifo[j]*(.01) + tempVal);`.

Comment: Java uses  `output[queueIn] = tempVal;`, C used `Output[i] = tempVal;`. Why the difference?

Comment: It's the exact same thing, I just fixed it though to make it consistent. It still gives me the same problem where the output is being replaced many times. I just forgot to change the values back after I was trying to debug it without the queueIn variable (in C).

Comment: Also, do you mean 1.0/10 instead of 1.0/4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your kernel is implemented for being run as NDRange and the main part when the calculations are done for Task (to be run as single work item) therefore each work item is overwriting the values.

Based on your Java implementation the NDRange kernel implementation should be something like this:

```
kernel void lowpass(__global float *Array, __global float *Output) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);

    float tempVal = 0.0f;
    for(int j = 0; j < idx+1; j++){ 
        tempVal += Array[j] * 0.01f;
    }

    Output[idx] = tempVal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great. A bit confused as to what you mean by 'implemented for being run as NDRange'.

Comment: NDRange means running many work items and at the beginning of your kernel you used `int idx = get_global_id(0);` which suggests NDRange type of kernel. For singe work item kernel you don't need that.

Comment: So would it be possible to code the same function without the NDRange type? I tried removing the get_global_id(0) but it still does the same thing.

Comment: No, you would have to reimplement the kernel to look more like on CPU however that would normally run very slow on GPU unless you want to run it on CPU then you could give it a try.